# Is $A$ is countable and closed?

Tags: general-topology

let  $\{V_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be  sequence   of open and dense  subsets  of  $\mathbb{R}$. set $A= \bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}V_n$
then $A$ is

choose the correct option

$1.)$ open

$2.)$ closed

$3.)$ countable

$4.)$ uncountable

My attempt: $A=\bigcap\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \big(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\big) = \{0\}$  so  option $2,3$ are correct

Is it true ?

Comment: Your sets are not dense.

Comment: @AndreasS  how   not dense  ??  i thinks  u  r  misguiding me

Comment: For example 2 is not a limit point of any set (-1/n,1/n). (Taking the definition of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set )
Hence your attempt does not work.

Comment: $A$ is dense means the closure of $A = \mathbb R$.  The closure of $(-\frac 1n, \frac 1n)$ is $[-\frac 1n, \frac 1n]$.  And that is not $\mathbb R$.

Comment: You are asked if the property is always true for all examples. So a particular (counter)example can only eliminate options by showing they are generally false, it cannot prove that the option is true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $r_1,r_2,...$ be an arrangement of the rationals. Let $V_n=\mathbb R \setminus \{r_n\}$. Then $V_n$ is a dense open set for each $n$ and $\cap_n V_n$ is the set of all irrational numbers. This proves that 1), 2) and 3) are false.

4) is true and this is a consequence of Baire Category Theorem. If $\cap_n V_n$ is a countable set $\{x_1,x_2,..\}$ then $\mathbb R =(\{x_1\} \cup  \{x_1\}\cup ...)\cup (V_1^{c}\cup V_2^{c} \cup...)$ and this contradicts the fact that the real line is of second category.